# Converting arrays to python scalars

Tags: python, numpy

I need to define this function:

() = ( − 2.5) * ^(−0.5( − 2)<sup>2</sup> + 0.2)

as a lambda function and then plot it in Python. This is what I have done so far:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1,5,100)
y = lambda a:  (a-2.5)*(math.exp(-0.5*((a-2)**2)))+ 0.2


plt.plot(x, y(x))
plt.show()
```

And I'm getting the error message `only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

The math module does not support exponentiating numpy arrays. Try `np.exp` instead. Full code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1,5,100)
y = lambda a:  (a-2.5)*(np.exp(-0.5*((a-2)**2)))+ 0.2



plt.plot(x, y(x))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem exist in `math.exp(-0.5*((a-2)**2))` you can't apply a function like this the `np.array` instead do this:

```
y = lambda a:  (a-2.5)*(np.array(list(map(math.exp,-0.5*((a-2)**2)))))+ 0.2
```